# How to refresh screen in SDL (SDL_RenderClear doesn't work)?

Tags: c++, sdl, codeblocks, sdl-2

I'm trying to make a simple program in CodeBlocks and SDL that changes the height of a rectangle every second. So far my code is this:

'''

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argv, char** args)
{
    SDL_Window *p;
    SDL_Renderer *w;

    p = SDL_CreateWindow("Temp",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,800,640,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    w = SDL_CreateRenderer(p, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(w,255,0,0,255);
    SDL_Rect Rect = {220,140,200,200};

//    int rectX = 220;
//    int rectY = 140;
//    int width = 200;
//    int height = 200;

    bool isRunning = true;
    SDL_Event event;

    int lastTime = 0;
    int currentTime = 0;

    while(isRunning)
    {
        // time stuff
        currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();
        int timeDifference = currentTime - lastTime;
        if(currentTime > lastTime + 1000)
        {
            lastTime = currentTime;
            height = 200;
        }
        // Check if window closes
        while ( SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if ( event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
            isRunning = false;
            }

            if ( event.type == SDL_KEYUP && event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
            {
            isRunning = false;
            }

        }
        // rectangle stuff
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(w,255,0,0,255);
        int newHeight = height + timeDifference / 4;
        Rect = {220,140,200,newHeight};

        SDL_RenderFillRect(w, &Rect);
        SDL_RenderPresent(w);
        SDL_Delay(10);

    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(w);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(p);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

'''

Every time it goes through the loop, the previous rectangles that were made are still there. Also, I have tried `SDL_RenderClear` but when it does that then the entire screen fills red. How do I fix this? I would just like it to refresh every time.

Also, I know that the previous rectangles stay because I tried it with a wired rectangle and it's more evident like that.

Comment: Where's your `SDL_Init()` call?  Are your window or renderer pointers NULL?

Comment: `RenderClear` clears render target with your current draw colour; you have to set desired clear (background) colour with `SetRenderDrawColor`, then clear. Of course before rendering your rectangle you'll need to specify wich colour it should be with `SetRenderDrawColor` again.